# ExtJs Tree Grid

Tags: extjs4

I want to implement treegrid using local proxy. Is it possible?
I have tried to make something like this

```
data:result,
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
```

and assign json string to "result" , it didn't gave me any error , but it didn't display anything on Grid , I mean my tree grid was totally blank, without any error.

Can I define TreeStore without proxy? as all data I have on page [locally].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `root:result` instead of `data:result`.

> Can I define TreeStore without proxy?

yes, you can. Check out example at [docs page](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel)

Comment: ohh , thats Gr8, Thanks a lot